Complex Analysis book in the spirit of Runge
Do there exist any complex analysis texts that take Runge's Theorem as the basis for defining analytic functions, and use that point of view in a serious way?  That is, they take analytic functions to be limits of rational functions, rather than starting with power series, integrals, etc?
This question is motivated by the introduction to Donald Marshall's complex analysis book, which says

There are four points
of view for this subject due primarily to Cauchy, Weierstrass, Riemann and Runge. Cauchy
thought of analytic functions in terms of a complex derivative and through his famous integral
formula. Weierstrass instead stressed the importance of power series expansions. Riemann
viewed analytic functions as locally rigid mappings from one region to another, a more geo-
metric point of view. Runge showed that analytic functions are nothing more than limits of
rational functions.

Though I knew Runge's theorem and its generalizations before, I never thought of it as a point of view on the level of Weierstrass/Riemann/Cauchy, but I have been increasingly thinking that it would be very interesting.
The closest thing I know is the central place given it as a one-dimensional analogue of the Cousin problem in Hormander's SCV text.
